# Как поместить модель в сессию в asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Модель NewModel приходит на контроллер, нужно ее поместить в сессию:

```
public ActionResult CreateForm(NewForm model)
{
      return RedirectToAction("EditForm");
}
```

В модели  заполненные данные от формы включая Id, мне нужно поместить модель в сессию, чтобы потом в дальнейшем использовать, например в редактировании формы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Session["MODEL_NEWFORM"] = model;
...
NewForm model = (NewForm)Session["MODEL_NEWFORM"];
```